# pnpm equivalent command for npm ci

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, pnpm, npm-ci

What is the equivalent command for `npm ci` in `pnpm`?

According to the documentation for [`npm install`](https://pnpm.io/cli/install):

> `pnpm install` is used to install all dependencies for a project.
>
> In a CI environment, installation fails if a lockfile is present but needs an update.

How is the "CI environment" defined?

What does the following mean? Dependencies could be updated, but the
`pnpm-lock.yaml` is not touched?

> `pnpm i --frozen-lockfile` `# pnpm-lock.yaml` is not updated

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> What is the equivalent command for npm ci in pnpm?

The equivalent is

```
pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
```

However, even if you don't use `--frozen-lockfile`, pnpm will automatically use a faster installation strategy if the lockfile is up-to-date. This is controlled by the [prefer-frozen-lockfile](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#prefer-frozen-lockfile) setting which is `true` by default.

> How is the "CI environment" defined?

pnpm uses the [is-ci](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ci) package to detect whether the environment is a CI.

> `pnpm i --frozen-lockfile # pnpm-lock.yaml is not updated`

It means that if the lockfile is not up-to-date with the `package.json` file then `pnpm install` will throw an exception instead of updating the lockfile. If the lockfile is up-to-date, pnpm will do any necessary updates to the `node_modules`.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but I found me in the same problem.
Hope to help someone with this.

In Unix-like environments (e.g. Linux), use

```bash
CI=true pnpm i
```

You can even set in the `package.json` a script called `ci` with this command, what will make `pnpm ci` work as expected.

In other environments, the idea is the same. Set the `CI` env variable to something truthy.

## Explanation

I'd investigate this question based on [Zoltan Kochan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70155300/13714095):

1. I found that [PNPM changed from using `is-ci` in favor of `ci-info`](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/main/pkg-manager/get-context/CHANGELOG.md#806) (from the same developer, and [`is-ci` itself uses `ci-info`](https://github.com/watson/is-ci/blob/6bae6da07ef8dc03f9cb0f6cd9fb1db0393ecd22/index.js#L3)).
2. In fact [PNPM uses this to determine if it's a CI environment](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/3ebce5db7af5a0c26fadca7eef15650ce68ac97b/pkg-manager/get-context/src/readLockfiles.ts#L55)
3. `ci-info` checks for several cloud vendors, [but it follows the `CI` environment variable if it is set](https://github.com/watson/ci-info/blob/20fae89d2bdeb0e5dd70e6a9e8d2647764e6ff04/index.js#L60)
4. I have tested this, and you can view or clone the code from: https://gist.github.com/40b75f11125cd9986611ec6b9b97b8b4.git
5. I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/6100) in the GitHub suggesting this command as a new feature.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I just wanted to know the equivalent command.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer, you explained how the CI environment was defined